# How to send message/notification to browser/client in Kendo Mvc Ajax Bound Grid (confirm update or create) ( by cookies)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

how to send notification to client in kendo mvc ajax bound ,

i do not know if this is good way ..
of course you can add ModelState.AddModelError("notification","….msg.")
and …. But it tell to datasource ajax action failed.. So..

**Addclass**:

```
public class AjaxErrorMsg
{
    public AjaxErrorMsg()
    {
        CssClass = "gray";
        AutoHide = false;
        AutoHideDelay = 200;
        Kind = "error";
        Title = "error";
    }

    public string Msg { get; set; }

    public string Kind { get; set; }

    public Boolean AutoHide { get; set; }
    public Int32 AutoHideDelay { get; set; }
    public string CssClass { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**In controller**

```
public void StoreMessageInCookie(string msg, Boolean isError = false, string msgDivClass = "", string preMessage = "", string msgTitle = "")
    {
        StoreMessageInCookie(new Exception(msg), isError, msgDivClass, preMessage, msgTitle);
    }
    public void StoreMessageInCookie(Exception ee, Boolean isError = false, string msgDivClass = "", string preMessage = "", string msgTitle = "")
    {
        List<AjaxErrorMsg> rs;
        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        if (this.Response.Cookies[Common1.MsgCookie].HasKeys )
        {
            try
            {
                rs = js.Deserialize<List<AjaxErrorMsg>>(this.Response.Cookies[Common1.MsgCookie].Value);
            }
            catch
            {
                rs = new List<AjaxErrorMsg>();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rs = new List<AjaxErrorMsg>();
        }

        var msg0 = new AjaxErrorMsg();
        if (isError)
        {
            msgDivClass = msgDivClass == "" ? "DivAlarmStyle6 fontMitra" : msgDivClass;
            msg0.Kind = "error";
            msg0.AutoHide = false;
            msg0.Title = "Error";
        }
        else
        {
            msg0.Kind = "alert";
            msg0.AutoHide = true;
            msg0.Title = "Warning";
        }
        msg0.Title = msgTitle == "" ? msg0.Title : msgTitle;

        msg0.Msg = preMessage + cm2.FilterMessageText(ee, IsAdminUser);

        if (msgDivClass.Trim() != "")
            msg0.Msg = Common1.WrapTextInDivWithClass(msg0.Msg, msgDivClass);

        rs.Add(msg0);
        this.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(Common1.MsgCookie, js.Serialize(rs)));
    }
```

cm2.FilterMessageText is function to remove database object name from error message string ..also include any inner exception message

**Then when you what to send message use command**

```
StoreMessageInCookie("Message 1 2 ! ");
```

And in your MainProject.js
Add all of code below

```js
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
          expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else   expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0)
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function ReadAnShowCookieForDeliverMessages() {
    try {
        var listMsg = readCookie("CookieForDeliverMessages")

        if (!!listMsg) {
            eraseCookie("CookieForDeliverMessages");
            ShowAndLogMessageListOfAjaxError($.parseJSON(listMsg));
        }
    } catch (ee) {
        alert(" error in  ReadAnShowCookieForDeliverMessages")
    }
}

function ShowAndLogMessageListOfAjaxError(ListOfAjaxError) {
    if (ListOfAjaxError == undefined)
        return;
    ListOfAjaxError.forEach(function (AjaxError) {
        ShowAndLogMessageByAjaxErrorClass(AjaxError)
    })
}

function ShowAndLogMessageByAjaxErrorClass(AjaxError) {
 
    if ((AjaxError != undefined) && (AjaxError.Msg != "")) {
// I used freeow => https://github.com/pjdietz/Freeow
        $("#freeow").freeow(AjaxError.Title, AjaxError.Msg, { classes: [AjaxError.CssClass, AjaxError.Kind], autoHide: AjaxError.AutoHide, autoHideDelay: AjaxError.AutoHideDelay });
 
     //   LogMsg(AjaxError.Msg, AjaxError.Title);  function to log message on client
    }
}
$(function () {
 
    MyAjaxSetting();
    ReadAnShowCookieForDeliverMessages();
}
function MyAjaxSetting() {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (o) {
 
        ReadAnShowCookieForDeliverMessages()
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to send it with `ActionResult`?

Comment: i don't know how to wrap in action result , the method is like this
    public ActionResult VmTKarkonanAmalkard_Create(Int64 parentIdAmalkard, [DataSourceRequest]
                                                       DataSourceRequest request, VmTKarkonanAmalkard m)
        {  .... return Json(new[] { m }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));..}

Comment: const string Common1.MsgCookie="CookieForDeliverMessages"